# Kotlin Can't create @Autowired field in Class that are annotated with @Configuration @EnableWebMvc

Tags: spring, kotlin

`Autowired` field is `null` when initializing the project:

```
package com.lynas.config

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse


@Component
open class InterceptorConfig : HandlerInterceptorAdapter() {

    override fun preHandle(request: HttpServletRequest, response: HttpServletResponse, handler: Any?): Boolean {

        return true
    }
}



package com.lynas.config

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.lynas")
open class WebConfig() : WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {

    // this field show null
    @Autowired
    lateinit var interceptorConfig: InterceptorConfig

    override fun addInterceptors(registry: InterceptorRegistry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(interceptorConfig)
    }

}
```

`lateinit var interceptorConfig: InterceptorConfig` is `null` when I run the application. How to fix this?

full code `https://github.com/lynas/kotlinSpringBug`

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot? If so, where is your bootstrap class located? It's recommended to put it inside of the root package and all other components in sub-packages. Perhaps your component scan is not working correctly. You can also leave out the `@EnableWebMvc` and `@ComponentScan`by replacing it with a single `@SpringBootApplication`. See also https://spring.io/blog/2016/02/15/developing-spring-boot-applications-with-kotlin for further information.

Comment: Its not spring boot application

Comment: `@Autowired` will be on the private field, which is fine for Spring.  You likely should check the rest of your app, sping config, class path scanning, etc.  I don't see anything that would be a Kotlin specific problem.

Comment: i think its kotlin problem since exact java code works perfectly. see the gist https://gist.github.com/lynas/9fe12c78c560876b3bc06cf03c217e4b

Comment: i have also tried `@Autowired
    private lateinit var interceptorConfig: InterceptorConfig`

Comment: Like others I can't see anything out of place - you could ditch component scanning and declare the bean in your `WebConfig` as a alternative solution (or just construct it inline in your `addInterceptors()` method as it doesn't seem to be spring aware anyway).

Comment: tried `open class WebConfig @Autowire constructor (val inc: InterceptorConfig) : WebMvcConfigurerAdapter()` . it does not work because it requires a default empty constructor. I cant create the bean in `WebConfig` because I need to use `@Service` class from InterceptorConfig class

Comment: @LynAs did you manage to find a solution to this problem?

Comment: no, i could not. i created a issue in kotlin issue tracker. they closed it saying that its not a problem on there part

Comment: I've been having the same issue and it's driving me nuts.

Comment: @aglassman did you manage to resolve this? driving me nuts as well

Comment: You know what @Kid101, I was able to resolve this, but for the live of me can't remember what I did.  I'll ask my co-worker tomorrow if he remembers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `@field:Autowired lateinit var interceptorConfig` or `@set:Autowired` which will tell kotlin compiler to put annotations explicitly on field/setter. by default it places them on "property" which is kotlin-only construct and Java may have problems accessing it. refer to [kotlin docs here](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets)

Comment: good find but it does not work. getting same error `lateinit property interceptorConfig has not been initialized`

Comment: Tested it spring boot 2. it works `@field:Autowired
    lateinit var demoService: DemoService`